# How to resolve (context: this)

Tags: java, android

I have problem in (this). the error ImageView cannot be applied. i do this code in fragment class.

```
ViewFlipper v_flipper;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    int images[] = {R.drawable.promo1, R.drawable.promo2, R.drawable.promo3};

    v_flipper = rootView.findViewById(R.id.v_flipper);

    for(int image: images){
        flipperImages(image);
    }

    return rootView;
}

public void flipperImages(int image){

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(image);


    v_flipper.addView(imageView);
    v_flipper.setFlipInterval(4000);
    v_flipper.setAutoStart(true);

    v_flipper.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    v_flipper.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

}
```

call from rootview that using for return value for fragment.

Comment: where is the `flipperImages` method called from? we need a bit more code

Comment: If you are in a Fragment, use "new ImageView(getContext())"... Just remember that getContext() can return null... So, it is better to check against null

Comment: @W0rmH0le thanks a lots !!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you're passing `this` in this line but that method isn't inside a correct context:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
```

To do that inside a Fragment, first you need to get the context it belongs with `getContext()`:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
```

But, without more information, I can't help you more.

Answer (score 0):

In fragment use getActivity() Like

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in your question refers to the class `Fragment` where as you want an instance of `Context` (which is a parent of `Activity`)

You can use

`new ImageView(getActivity());`
or
`new ImageView(getContext());`